# Jquery focus in/out chain event

Tags: jquery

I have multiple input boxes, the 2 I'm testing it on are #StartTime and #EndTime

What I want is, when you click off the #StartTime to validate it and the #EndTime, unless they move directly to the #EndTime

There is custom validation on the model to check the start is before the end etc

```
<script name="focus off StartTime">
    $("#StartTime").focusout(function () {
        console.log("focus out");
        if ($("#EndTime").is(":focus") == false) {
            $("#EndTime").removeData("previousValue").valid();
            console.log($("#MondayEndAm").is(":focus"));
        } 
    });
</script>
```

This is just a snippet for testing.  Issue I am having is, regardless of what input box I select directly after the #StartTime returns false.  Is there some sort of chain event broken when i .focusout?

Comment: You need to delay your check a little, e.g, just using a timeout

Comment: Great stuff, thanks mate.